# Blog Network Engine Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

Is there a Ruby equivalent to Wordpress multiuser/multi site, which allows one to run a network of blogs?  If so, what is it?

Comment: There is Typo, but I am not sure if that supports multi siteing. You could implement it, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are two

[locomotivecms](http://locomotivecms.com/)

[radiantcms](http://radiantcms.org/) and here it says [how to do it](http://www.funonrails.com/2009/09/multiple-sites-hosting-using-radiant.html)

:)